# How to return a result set of a table in DB2-LUW without using a cursor?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in DB2-LUWv10.5. I need to return a result set of a table without making use of a Cursor(WITH RETURN).

I am running the below code on DB2-LUWv10.5. When I use Approach2, it runs fine and returns expected result set as output i.e. Salary and bonus of all employees. However, when I use Approach1, it gives me an error.

Errors encountered:

1. "," was expected instead of ";".
2. "salary, bonus" appears to be misplaced.
3. End of text was reached after "p1".

Approach 1:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  read_emp()
  SPECIFIC read_emp
  LANGUAGE SQL 
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

  p1:  BEGIN

      SELECT salary, bonus
      FROM employee;

  END p1
```

Approach 2:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE  read_emp()
  SPECIFIC read_emp
  LANGUAGE SQL 
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

  p1:  BEGIN

DECLARE c_emp CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
      SELECT salary, bonus
      FROM employee;

    OPEN c_emp;

  END p1
```

Expected output -

```
Salary Bonus
25000  2500
30000  3000
50000  5000
40000  4000
45000  4500
```

Comment: Hello TT, just added them.

Comment: You cannot use bare `SELECT` in Db2 SQL PL compound statements; you must `SELECT ... INTO` something. Why is it that you don't want to use a cursor if it works as you expect?

Comment: Cursor works as expected. However, I need to know whether there is any other solution available in Db2 to return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Approach 1" is invalid syntax, and Db2 will reject it, because that's the design.

A stored procedure that wants to return a result-set via the `dynamic result set` syntax must declare and open at least one cursor.

But a stored procedure does not necessarily have to use the dynamic result set syntax. A stored procedure is free to use an OUTPUT parameter that is either a weakly-typed-cursor or a strongly-typed-cursor data-type. The stored procedure must still open the cursor however, just that it can pass the opened cursor back as a parameter.  The caller will still need to consume that cursor however.

User Defined Functions can return tables, this is an alternative approach, so callers don't then need to use explicit cursors to access the resulting data.